# How to import your package/modules from a script in bin folder in python

Tags: python

When organising python project, this structure seems to be a standard way of doing it:

```
myproject\
    bin\
        myscript
    mypackage\
        __init__.py
        core.py
    tests\
        __init__.py
        mypackage_tests.py
setup.py
```

My question is, how do I import my `core.py` so I can use it in `myscript`?

both `__init__.py` files are empty.

Content of `myscript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mypackage import core
if __name__ == '__main__':
    core.main()
```

Content of `core.py`

```
def main():
    print 'hello'
```

When I run `myscript` from inside `myproject` directory, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/myscript", line 2, in <module>
    from mypackage import core
ImportError: No module named mypackage
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your `sys.path` value (modified by the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or at run time by Python code) determines where `import` will search for modules.

Comment: Consider using `entry_points["console_scripts"]'` in `setup.py`.

Comment: What are the contents of `setup.py`?  And is it in the myproject directory?

Comment: Why not install your package (`python setup.py etc`) *before* running your script?

Comment: I'm in a development stage, so I'd rather not install it every time I make a change to see if it works.

Comment: Don't need to install every time. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816683/972128

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, `setup.py` should install the package in a place where the Python interpreter can find it, so after installation `import mypackage` will work.  To facilitate running the scripts in `bin` right from the development tree, I'd usually simply add a simlink to `../mypackage/` to the `bin` directory.  Of course, this requires a filesystem supporting symlinks…

Comment: Using the symlink as you suggested, the script was able to find mypackage, but I've now run into another issue... See my edit above in the question.

Comment: Instead of using "clever" symlinks with development, use a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/) and run `python setup.py develop` to have distutils install the executable in your path (when you have activated that virtualenv)

Comment: Actually, I figured it out that other issue.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: virtualenv seems like a good solution, I'll have to learn more about it.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I agree that virtualenv is the more flexible and robust solution.  However, for simple situations (a single module or package), using a symlink always worked fine for me.  The symlink is easier to set up and allows testing command-line tools without running `python setup.py`, so it also has its merits.

Comment: @SvenMarnach a single module or package? better to be prepared for the future ;p

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a "best choice", but the following is my normal practice:

1. Put whatever script I wanna run in /bin
2. do "python -m bin.script" in the dir myproject
3. When importing in script.py, consider the dir in which script.py is sitting as root. So

   ```
   from ..mypackage import core
   ```

If the system supports symlink, it's a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add my bin path into $PYTHONPATH, that will enable python to look for asked module in bin directory too.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/bin:$PYTHONPATH
$ python
import module_from_bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue following [setuptools specifications](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages).

**In setup.py** you can specify the modules **`as an argument for the function setup()`**:

```
packages = find_packages()
```

This finds all modules.

p.s. you have to import this function: `from setuptools import setup, find_packages`