# Relative imports from parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have project structure as you can see below:
some API module, which i use to make some tools.

```
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── some_script.py
├── tools
│   └── tool1.py
```

api/some_script.py

```
def func():
    print("Func1")

class some_object():
      ...
```

api/__init__.py

```
from .some_script import some_object, func
```

Where in tool1.py is

```
from ..api import func
```

I want that tools in folder, but I keep getting import error. To this point I had tool1.py in no folder and it worked fine (but with code
**from api import func**)

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How to make it work this way?
Thanks for answers

Comment: Add the missing `__inits__` to `tools` and parent

Comment: The parent folder is the development folder, there should not be any init 
The tool script is the one I run from terminal

Comment: Then you can't import form the same package structure. That's just not how it's done

Comment: Well, in pycharm it recognizes the package and script runs as it should, but when I run it from terminal, it does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import your package/modules from a script in bin folder in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612743/how-to-import-your-package-modules-from-a-script-in-bin-folder-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got the same error, turns out you need to help the import using sys here is how to do it:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append("..")
from api import some_script
```

Answer (score 0):

@basic beatle
helped me solve it. With some other sources and this one works:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
```